# prevent showing image on drag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to create drag uploader :

I have used an image for darg area :

and I used this script for the showing a notfication on drag :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.dargbar').bind('drop', function(e) {
            alert('yes');
        });

    });

</script>
```

When I drag an image , it shows message successfully , but automatically loads image in browser . how can I stop loading image ?

thanks

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Try to [prevent default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) behavior:

```
$('.dargbar').bind('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('yes');
});
```

Or more supported by jQuery:

```
$('.dargbar').bind('drop', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    alert('yes');
});
```